Generate astro static html with relative paths
How to generate actuall static HTML pages from astro that I will be able to open without any CDN. Just to open index.html from file system. Now astro includes / at begining of each link that doesn't work in my case.
instead of
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_astro/hoisted.83c691aa.css" />

do
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_astro/hoisted.83c691aa.css" />

and hrefs to other static HTML files
so instead of
<a href="/docs" class="astro-BIH2FJRL">Docs</a>

do
<a href="docs/index.html" class="astro-BIH2FJRL">Docs</a>

So it will work without any special server
this is my astro.config.mjs
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

export default defineConfig({
  output: 'static',
  trailingSlash: 'never',
  build: {
    format: 'directory',
  },
});


Have you tried setting base?

yes it doesn't work also

Yeah, weird that base: "foo" is treated as /foo instead of ./foo. Perhaps worth asking for the feature on https://github.com/withastro/roadmap/discussions
